# Are these definitions for the limit of a sequence equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

D1: Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence and let $L$ be a real number. We say that $(a_n)$ converges to $L$ if for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that for every $n>N$ we have $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$

D2: Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence and let $L$ be a real number. We say that $(a_n)$ converges to $L$ if for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that for every $n>N$ we have $|a_n-L|\le \epsilon$

It's trivial that D1 implies D2. If $|a_n-L|\le \epsilon$ then we know that there exists an $\epsilon_2$ such that $\epsilon_2<\epsilon$ and $|a_n-L|\le \epsilon_2$ is eventually true and therefore $|a_n-L|\le \epsilon_2<\epsilon$ therefore $|a_n-L|< \epsilon$.
Is there a simpler proof than this?

Comment: The second part of your proof should start with "If $\epsilon>0$" and not with "If $|a_n-L|\leq\epsilon$", otherwise it seems okay and as clear as possible to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that $D_2$ implies $D_1$ is simple, let $(a_n)$ be a sequence and let $L$ be a real number, suppose that $(a_n)$ converges to $L$ in the sense of $D_2$. Let $\epsilon >0$, define $\epsilon':= \epsilon/2$, note that $\epsilon'>0$, then there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n > N$ we have $|a_n - L| \leq \epsilon' = \epsilon/2  < \epsilon$, and then $(a_n)$ converges to $L$ in the sense of $D_1$.